# Не устанавливаются плагины в ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gulp

Установил gulp, npm. Пытаюсь установить sass, но вылезает куча ошибок в терминале. В файле package.json нет sass. Nodejs и gulp установлены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выглядит, как будто не хватает прав на работу в каталоге (но скопировать с картинки сложно, поэтому, какой именно каталог - придется самому догадаться). проверьте на него права с помощью `ls -al` и потом поправьте с помощью chown/chmod или прям с mc/менеджера файлов.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @KoVadim. Выложи текст как текст. А то тестить на своих мощностях то что ты там навводил - сложновато.